# How to get first and last element in list item using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    function editMediaInfo(mediaID){
        var nex = document.getElementById(mediaID).nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.id;
        alert(nex);
        console.log(nex);
    }
</script>

<?php
$x = 1;
echo "<ul>";

while($x <= 5)
{
    echo "<li id={$x}> item {$x} </li>";    
    ?>
    <button onclick="editMediaInfo('<?php echo $x; ?>')">Click</button>
    <?php
    $x++;
}

echo "</ul>";   
?>
```

When I click any button (except item 5) it gives me an alert with next id element and this normal what I need here to do that when I click button item 5 give me another alert I tried to do this but every time console give me this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
```

Comment: there isn't a next sibling for the 5th item that's why

Comment: yes i know but i need to put if condition if there is next sibling alert something and if not alert another someting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the Id of the element if only it exists! I've added the if condition for that.

```
function editMediaInfo(mediaID){
var nex =   document.getElementById(mediaID).nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
var nextId="";
if(nex!=null){
  nextId=nex.id;
  alert(nextId);
}
else{
alert("no next element");
}
console.log(nextId);
}
```

Comment: I am very thankful it's work i appreciate your interest